# How do I start a Spring Integration DSL Poller from a generic MessageSource

Tags: spring, spring-integration

One of our Spring Integration DSL flows is meant to be a simple poller based on a cron expression. Normally you would configure a PollableChannel implementation (e.g. QueueChannel) or by using an InboundAdapter (e.g. FTP, HTTPS, S3 etc.) to process inbound messages which have a polling property.

In our case, we won't have any inbound Messages to process. We simply want to start the SI DSL based IntegrationFlow on a nightly basis preferably using a cron expression. Is there any way that we can start a SI Flow with a poller or "fake" a message based on a cron job?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
IntegrationFlows
        .from(() -> new GenericMessage<>(""),
                e -> e.poller(p -> p.cron("0 0 0 * * ?")))
```

Since there is no something like `NullMessage` or `Message` with `null` payload, we just send a "fake" message with empty string as payload. You can just ignore that message downstream.

The first Lambda is implementation of the `MessageSource<T>` exactly what you mentioned about (S)FTP, S3, JDBC etc.

It will be still the same Inbound Channel Adapter, a-la equivalent for the `<int:inbound-channel-adapter ref="">`

Comment: This is perfect! It's a much better than our solution. :-)

We figured out another way to do this using the MethodInvokingMessageSource on AtomicInteger to *theoretically* maintain concurrency.

@Bean(value = "wiirMessageSource")
    public MessageSource<?> wiirMessageSource() {
        MethodInvokingMessageSource source = new MethodInvokingMessageSource();
        source.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        source.setObject(new AtomicInteger());
        source.setMethodName("getAndIncrement");

        return source;
    }

We could then implement the poller lambda using that.

Comment: Good. A note: since it is a `@Bean` already, you don't need to set `beanFactory` manually it is done by the container automatically.

Comment: I get this error with the solution proposed: The target type of this expression must be a functional interface Using SI 4.3, am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: Oh forget it, eclipse was trolling me badly :(